# ARM template - website deployment failure

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I’m attempting to use Azure Resource manager (ARM) template files to deploy as ASP.net website and am hitting a roadblock. This is a nascent feature of Azure so there isn’t much know-how out on the web about it, hoping someone here can help instead.

I can successfully create a new site (i.e. a Microsoft.Web/sites resource) in a new resource group i.e. it works when I define a website in the ARM template like so:

```
{
  "apiVersion": "2014-06-01",
  "name": "[parameters('siteName')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
  "location": "[parameters('siteLocation')]",
  "tags": {
    "[concat('hidden-related:', resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]": "Resource",
    "displayName": "Website"

  },
  "dependsOn": [
    "[concat('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "name": "[parameters('siteName')]",
    "serverFarm": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]"
  }
}
```

My problem comes when I try to deploy an ASP.net website into it. Here’s what I have added to my ARM template:

```
{
  "apiVersion": "2014-06-01",
  "name": "[parameters('siteName')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
  "location": "[parameters('siteLocation')]",
  "tags": {
    "[concat('hidden-related:', resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]": "Resource",
    "displayName": "Website"

  },
  "dependsOn": [
    "[concat('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "name": "[parameters('siteName')]",
    "serverFarm": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2014-06-01",
      "type": "extensions",
      "name": "MSDeploy",
      "dependsOn": [ "[concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/', parameters('siteName'))]" ],
      "properties": {
        "connectionString": "",
        "dbType": "",
        "packageUri": "file:///D:/svn/dh.PSP.Conductor/dh.PSP.Conductor.AzureResourceGroup/obj/Release/ProjectReferences/dh.PSP.Conductor.Api/package.zip"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I’m deploying from PowerShell and it fails with:

> New-AzureResourceGroup : 16:00:35 - Resource
>   Microsoft.Web/sites/extensions 'ARMTest20150604/MSDeploy' failed with
>   message 'The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning
>   state 'Failed'.'

If I look in the portal I see a slightly more useful  error:

> statusCode:Conflict
>   statusMessage:{"status":"Failed","error":{"code":"ResourceDeploymentFailure","message":"The
>   resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state
>   'Failed'."}}

[image]
I’m none the wiser as to why this is failing however. Can anyone suggest how I might investigate further?

Comment: There is now a nice troubleshooting article available for tis type of issue: https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/virtual-machines/resource-group-deploy-debug.md

Comment: @DeChrist link broken, can you update with new link?. Thanks

Comment: @jayasurya_j It has loosely ended up at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/common-deployment-errors

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Fault is mine (as you might expect). Its not possible to reference a local file for the packageUri property, the file needs to be uploaded to blob storage first.

Something else useful I've found out, a deployment log is available by browsing to https://websitename.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole, "cd logfiles\siteextensions\msdeploy", open appManagerLog.xml. Much more useful information in there. In my case:

```
<entry time="2015-06-04T15:28:12.0718158+00:00" type="Error">
        <message>AppGallery Deploy Failed: 'System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The URI is empty.
   at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
   at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.AppGalleryPackage.IsPremiumApp()
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.DeploymentController.CheckCanDeployIfAppIsPremium(AppGalleryPackageInfo packageInfo, Boolean&amp;amp; isPremium)'</message>
    </entry>
    <entry time="2015-06-04T15:28:12.1186872Z" type="Message">
        <message>Downloading package path 'D:\svn\dh.PSP.Conductor\dh.PSP.Conductor.AzureResourceGroup\obj\Release\ProjectReferences\dh.PSP.Conductor.Api\package.zip' from blob ''</message>
    </entry>
    <entry time="2015-06-04T15:28:12.1186872Z" type="Error">
        <message>Failed to download package.</message>
    </entry>
```

Comment: Thanks very useful indeed. I just discovered Kudu

Comment: Especially useful: Have a look in the file LogFiles/SiteExtensions/WebDeploy/appManagerLog.xml

Comment: It's LogFiles/SiteExtensions/MSDeploy/appManagerLog.xml

Comment: i uploaded the package to blob but when i refer it in template i get uri format exception. invalid uri scheme. have you experienced that?

Comment: True, the uri field does not accept a valid file:/// identifier, but as an alternative to using a blob http:// uri, you can use any http:// accessable source, most conveniently one generated by GitHub for an individual file.